# How to talk to service from outside in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service

In a lot of examples, angular services have been calling out to functions defined outsides of angular.

How would I invoke an Angular Service from an outside function?

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SearchService {
    search(string) {
        ......
    }

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, ...){}
}

// outside function
function searchForContent(string) {
    // need to get the service here
    return service.search(string);
}
```

EDIT:

I am looking for a way that ensures that consuming this service via DI will also deliver from the singleton

Comment: This is considered an anti-pattern. But is there any good reason you are doing this instead of injecting your service to the component that needs it?

Comment: I have a lot of problems integrating a external button from external enterprise, 1. problems ultiple calls  with addlistener ,this link  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63293764, for that the last part, I need to call a service from outside of the normal component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is considered an **Anti-Pattern for Angular Applications**. However, if you have specific purposes for it and really need to do it here is how you will be able to use your service outside angular:

Let's say we have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  testMethod() {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Now you can do this on your App Component, or even on your main.ts file. You can choose where to put the following code below depending on when you want to expose your service globally. But let's say you want to expose the service when your App Component is called:

At the top of your **app.component.ts**

```
declare var window: any;

window.tryTestService = function tryTestService() {
  let myTestService = new TestService();
  myTestService.testMethod();
}

// Now you can use this anywhere. (You can even drop the 'window' as it is global)
window.tryTestService();
```

That's it. Basically you just instantiate your service and add it to the global "window" object. Now you can call it anywhere:

[image]

You can also just directly add an instance of your service to window object by doing like this:

```
declare var window: any;

window.TestServiceInstance = new TestService();
window.TestServiceInstance.testMethod(); // Call the methods of your service.
```

**Note:**

This example is simple enough since we don't have much going on our service and we don't have any other dependencies as well in our TestService. However, things starts to get complicated when you have other dependencies on your service, since you will have to inject them or instantiate them as well to fully construct your service. Angular does all this heavy lifting for you with its powerful Dependency Injection system, provided you are doing it the "Angular way" or inside Angular's context.

Comment: Do you get the same instance as the injected or a separate instance? Also how to handle dep injection in this manner?

Comment: No you do not get the same instance as in this case your are instantiating a new one. If you want to get the same instance, inject the service in your component constructor, and then use that injected service object to add to the "window" object like this:

window.TestServiceInstance = testService;

Comment: Provided that you injected your service on your component constructor of course. eg.:

constructor(private testService: TestService) {}